# Angular filter array by multiple strings

Tags: angular, typescript

I have array i need to filter it by multiple values

```js
data1 = [
  {
    "status": "60"
  },
  {
    "status": "70"
  }, 
  // so on
];
```

I am doing like this its working with single string not with multiple

```js
var countsettled = this.data1.filter((obj) => obj.status === '60' || '61' || '62' || '63' || '64' || '75').length;
var countunsettled = this.data1.filter((obj) => obj.status === '71' || '72' || '73' || '74' || '31' || '32' || '33' || '34' || '66').length;
```

Comment: Not sure why this is closed. The question is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify a property for each comparison:

```js
var countsettled = this.data1.filter((obj) => obj.status === '60' || obj.status === '61' || obj.status === '62' || obj.status === '63' || obj.status === '64' || obj.status === '75').length;
```

An alternate way to do this more concisely will be to use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var countsettledStatus = [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 75];
var countsettled = this.data1.filter((obj) => countsettledStatus.includes(obj.status)).length;
```

**IE11 Polyfill**

Add the polyfill in your `polyfill.ts` file:

```
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Even if IE doesn't natively support Array.inclides(..), this can be added to your polyfill file if Angular doesn't already include it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the browser support `indexOf`.

`var countsettled  = this.data1.filter(f=> ['60','61','62'].indexOf(f.status)!=-1).length;`